# Reason for Apache 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, 503-error

There are several possibilities why apache returns 503 - Service Unavailable:

- MaxConnPerIP
- MaxClients
- ...

The application is kallithea (a source code management system for git). I could not find anythings in the application logs.

I guess apache returns 503 since there is too much load or not enough workers.

I don't like guessing.

Up to now I found no way to see the reason why apache returns a 503.

I set `LogLevel info` in apache.

I am not married with apache. If this is a well known issue, please tell me. I am willing to switch to a different web server, if other web servers don't hide reasons.

Comment: What does Apache error log tell?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen The access log shows the 503. But in the error logs I can't find anything matching to this request.

Comment: If Apache is only logging a 503 in the access log then the problem is almost always with the underlying service Apache is talking to. I'd start with the kallithea logs. If there was a problem with the number of connections or other components of the proxy config there would normally be something in the error log too.